# Getting rounded corners in a google chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts to draw a column chart but i need the rectangular bars to have rounded corners. Can anybody help me with this??.
I have used google charts api to draw the charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out Material Charts https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Material

Haven't found another way to draw rounded corners in Google Charts so far.